# Add missing rows on mysql query with zero value

Tags: mysql

The issue is this, I have a query that returns a date and a count for that specific date, but what I want is that the dates that not appear in that range (because don't exist in the table) appear but with a zero value.

My query is this:

```
     SELECT fechacierre, COUNT(idcliente) as cantidad
     FROM cliente
     WHERE fechacierre BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2017-02-21', INTERVAL -6 DAY) AND '2017-02-21'
     GROUP BY fechacierre
```

Giving this result:

```
------------------------
fechacierre | cantidad
------------------------
2017-02-15  | 3
------------------------
2017-02-17  | 1
------------------------
2017-02-20  | 3
------------------------
2017-02-21  | 2
------------------------
```

How can I get the values for (2017-02-16), (2017-02-18) and (2017-02-19) with a 0 value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is something you should do in the code that calls the SQL, like php or whatever you're running on your server. It can be done in SQL, but you will need another table with a row per date in the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an aux table with all dates you need like this:

```
select @rowNum := @rowNum +1, DATE_ADD('2017-02-21', INTERVAL -@rownum DAY) as fechacierre from Any_table_with_some_records, (select @rowNum := 0) t
```

Then you can right join

```
SELECT fechacierre, COUNT(idcliente) as cantidad
FROM cliente
RIGHT JOIN aux ON aux.fechacierre = cliente.fechacierre
WHERE fechacierre BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2017-02-21', INTERVAL -6 DAY) AND '2017-02-21'
     GROUP BY fechacierre
```

It's an idea, i did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it doing a RIGHT JOIN with a table that has all the days like this:

```
SELECT fechacierre, COUNT(idcliente) as cantidad
     FROM cliente RIGHT JOIN (select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between DATE_ADD('2017-02-21', INTERVAL -6 DAY) and '2017-02-21') t ON fechacierre = selected_date
     WHERE fechacierre BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2017-02-21', INTERVAL -6 DAY) AND '2017-02-21'
     GROUP BY fechacierre
```